# Check if a MySQL row was inserted within the last 24 hours using PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I need to run a check to determine if a row was inserted into the database within the last 24 hours. No matter what I do, it always comes back saying that I've created a row. (whether I change the INTERVAL 1 DAY to INTERVAL 1 Month, INTERVAL 1 Year, INTERVAL 1 Second, etc.)

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Also, any info you can provide as to how to debug this would be great.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE id = " . $id . " AND cdate >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY")) {
  echo 'Row created within the last 24 hours';
} else {
  echo 'Row not created within the last 24 hours';
}
```

The database table contains a the column `cdate` and is set to `DATETIME` with a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Here's an example of one of the values `2015-08-20 21:14:30`

Comment: you're also not "preparing" anything so just use `query` rather than `prepare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement doesn't make a lot of sense because you're not actually evaluating anything, your just preparing a statement to be executed (but you're also forgetting to execute it). Assuming your SQL statement works, this will execute the result and check the number of rows correctly:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE id = " . $id . " AND cdate >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* store result */
        $stmt->store_result();

        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            echo 'Row created within the last 24 hours';
        } else {
            echo 'Row not created within the last 24 hours';
        }

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried out your code, but it keeps showing "Row created..." after I change INTERVAL 1 DAY to INTERVAL 1 MONTH. Any ideas? The row (only one in the table) was created around two hours ago, so if I bump up the interval to one month, it shouldn't find any rows, correct?

Comment: Can you echo out `$query` and run it through something like phpMyAdmin to verify that it's the PHP and not the SQL statement that's not working?

Comment: Tried what you suggested and the row is showing up in the results for the query in phpMyAdmin. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using quotes around `$id`? Try
    `$query = "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE id = '" . $id . "' AND cdate >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";`

Answer (score 2):

`$stmt` is the statement object, not the result of the query.
(You've prepared the query and not yet executed it.)

I'd recommend you read over the docs carefully, all you need is here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Specifically you're looking for how to execute the prepared query (`$stmt`) and how to retrieve the result-set.

Example code on the docs page.

---

If you remain really stuck, look up  the method you're calling.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

The return result of it is a statement object on success - false otherwise.

PHP is not type strict - meaning it'll try to compare things "logically" rather than "strictly".  An object is "true" (in your conditional statement) - thus it prints out what you see.

For debug you could simply use:

```
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($stmt);
```

(Or use xdebug with NetBeans' break points and inspection if you want to get serious: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

That'll output details of what the variable is - which might shed light.

Let me know if you're coming from another language, someone might have hints to get you running faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your query!

You can try to change it to:

```
$response = $mysqli->query("...");
```

For executing it is:

```
$stmt ->execute();
```